# change camera position in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, animation

I saw a presentation some years ago and it had a nice transition between texts. It seemed that had only one slide with a big picture like this:

[image]

And instead of changing slides, position of camera changed during time or user click. For example at beginning, you could see above image. Then camera rotated and changed it's position across `z` and `y` axis so it seemed zoomed:

[image]

And then again camera rotated and changed it's position:

[image]

And so on, until the end of presentation which you could see the first image.

1. What is the name of this effect?
2. Is that a specific type of animation?
3. Is it possible to do like that in PowerPoint (better on 2003)? If no, how I can achieve some thing like that?

Comment: Sounds like a fancy [prezi](http://www.prezi.com) thing. Otherwise ... zoom and move? There are transition effects and animations that allow you to move parts of a presentation or allow you to have a transition. Haveing an animation that moves/zooms the graphic or possibly multiple graphics could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect they actually had separate slides, where each slide had an opening animation that started off matching the previous slide, then moved appropriately to the new state. Alternatively, they may have been using an add-in of some description to match the effect. I'm certainly not aware of any other way to achieve that result with standard PowerPoint tools.